# Devexpress gridview add blank row

Tags: gridview, devexpress, addition, rows

[picture_DevExPressGridviewAddblankRow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DowDF.jpg)

Hello,

As you can see at attached screenshot, I want to add new row to bottom.
( NewItemRowPosition = Bottom, Edit = true, etc.. but doesn't work.)

Please help me.

Thanks,
Best Regards.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set the data source of the GridView?

Comment: I don't use datasource. I need only blank row.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to display the New Item Row in conjunction with a GridControl that does not have a data source. Per the [New Item Row documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument778):

> [T]he new item row - a row that allows end-users to add new records.
>   **Note that this row can only be used if the data source supports the**
>   **addition of new rows** (for instance, when your data source implements
>   the IBindingList interface and the IBindingList.AllowNew property
>   value is true).

So in a nutshell: no data source = no New Item Row.

Answer (score 0):

In gridview properties you should do following:

1. OptionsNavigation - AutoFocusNewRow = true
2. OptionsView - NewItemRowPosition = Bottom
3. OptionsBehaviour.Editable = true

And of course gridview should have datasource binded